# How can I get access to the items within "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, object

How can I get access to the items within "this" so that I can chain further elements onto a "this" object?

I am sure I am not understading something and doing it the long way around, but currently taking a "this" object and manually parsing out the string of items in the element so I can then add further specification

I originally thought I could just:

$(this)  + " ul li";

but that just seems to try to add a string to [object HTMLDivElement]

So I then manually extracted and contacenated all the elements together as a string:

```
function cleanThis(el) { return el.replace(/^ +/,"").replace(/ +$/,"").replace(/  +/g," ") }
function parseThis(el) { return el.tagName + (el.id?"#"+cleanThis(el.id):"") + (el.className?"."+cleanThis(el.className).replace(/ /g,"."):"") }

var eachThis = $(parseThis(this)  + " ul li");
```

This seems like I am recreating the wheel and that I should be able to access the information I need in JQuery or Javascript

So if
$(this) = jQuery(div#nav)

How can I get access to "div#nav" so that I can actually add further specification such as the example above with eachThis (adding on: " ul li")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

```
$( this ).find( 'ul li' );
```

Another way is to provide the containing element [as a parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1):

```
$( 'ul li', $( this ) );
```

Comment: `$('ul li', $(this));` can just be written as `$('ul li', this);`

Comment: Yes! Thank you one and all, especially Juhana and Rocket. This is exactly what I was trying to find!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `<ul>` to whatever node is inside $(this)?

```
$(this).append('<ul><li>');
```